# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'default_locale' of non-object. I cannot seem to find the problem here

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, composer-php

```
<?php

namespace Webkul\Shop\Http\Middleware;

use Webkul\Core\Repositories\LocaleRepository;
use Closure;

class Locale
{
    /**
     * @var LocaleRepository
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * @param \Webkul\Core\Repositories\LocaleRepository $locale
     */
    public function __construct(LocaleRepository $locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = request()->get('locale');

        if ($locale) {
            if ($this->locale->findOneByField('code', $locale)) {
                app()->setLocale($locale);

                session()->put('locale', $locale);
            }
        } else {
            if ($locale = session()->get('locale')) {
                app()->setLocale($locale);
            } else {
                app()->setLocale(core()->getDefaultChannel()->default_locale->code);
            }
        }

        unset($request['locale']);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, its because the column name which is supposed to hold the default_locale is unknown in the database so there is nothing. is there any way I can change this to be null incase the column object can't be read ? or some sort of bypassing this requirement?

Comment: How is this related to MySQL, vue.js, or Composer?

Answer (score -1):

```
core()->getDefaultChannel()
```

It returns non-object

Comment: can it be replaced ?

Comment: Check that `Webkul\Core\Contracts\Channel` data exists and `config('app.channel')` valid

Comment: Webkul\Core\Contracts\Channel.php class is empty

Comment: It can be wrapped into `optional` like that `optional(optional(core()->getDefaultChannel())->default_locale)->code ?? config('app.fallback_locale')`